# HOW do I reduced the margin between my division elements in my vue.js project?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, vuejs2

How do I align my division elements containing a Text and Image closer to each other?

This is the code :

This division elements contain paragaph elements and image elements that, but margin between the division element too much.

```
<template lang = "html">

<div class = "">

  <h1>{{ Help }}</h1>
          <div class = "container">
        <div class = "row">


          <form>
                <input type="text" name="search" placeholder = "Search : Tutorial, FAQS, Contacts "class = " form-control input-lg" height = "">
          </form>


        </div>
        </div>

<div class = "container">

        <div class = "row">

                  <h2>levi basics</h2>

                <h3>What is levi?</h3>

                <p class = "" id = "Headline"> levi is data curation software. This means that from <b>collection</b> to <b>sharing</b> to <b>analyzing</b> of data, levi refines each step  in that process to provide wellbeing for institutions.</p>


          <h3>How does levi function?</h3>


<div class = "col-sm-4">

          <p class = "lead">levi receives data.</p>


            </div>

                      <div class = "col-sm-4" id = "align">
                                  <p class = "lead">levi will analyse data over time to show the historical behaviour of your business. </p>
                                  <img src = "../../assets/GraphAnalysis.png" alt = "GraphAnalysis" width = "200" height = "150" class = "Img">
                      </div>

                <div class = "col-sm-4">
                          <p class = "lead">levi will share data with those who need it and help businesses collaborate with each other better!</p>
                          <img src = "../../assets/DataShare.jpg" alt = "GraphAnalysis" width = "300" height = "150" class = "Img">

                </div>
        </div>
</div>

</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Support',
  data() {
    return {

      Help: 'How can levi Help?',

    };
  },
};
</script>

<style lang = "css" scoped >

h1 { font-size: 90px; text-align: center; font-family: Heiti SC; font-weight: bolder;  line-height: 1em; margin-top: 90px; }

h2 { text-align: center; font-family: Heiti SC;  font-size: 50px; }

h3 { font-family: Heiti SC;  margin-top: 50px; font-size: 60px; }


 input {
    border: solid 1px 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    height: 60px;

}


 input[placeholder = Search] {
font-size: 90px;

}

#Headline {
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  font-family: Heiti SC;
  font-weight: lighter;
}
</style>
```

This is JS fiddle for how the page looks.

[JS fiddle Help page](https://jsfiddle.net/whtrzgxh/6/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to reset the initial styling to have `margin-bottom: 0;` It's common within vue components to have the component name as the highest level `<div></div>` element.

In your css you could then reset all p tags by doing;

```
.Support p{
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

The above would target all p elements that are found within your template as your using the scoped attribute. In the case you have global styles that are overriding the component css you may need to add the `!important` attribute giving you `margin-bottom: 0 !important;` which will make it a higher priority style than regular initialized styles such as above.